# Can I ask questions about Sikhism?

Tags: discussion

Can I ask questions about Sikhism because it shares almost the same belief.

And there is no website about it.

Comment: So you finally did discover what i said, that they have the same belief?

Comment: @Archit yesss

Comment: Proud of you . Chal here’s your upvote...

Comment:  Thanks

Comment: Yes, but they will be closed as off topic @DarkKnight

Comment: @Rickross so I can't ask questions about Sikhism because it is off topic.

Comment: Questions that are related to Hinduism are on topic here. If your questions are entirely related to Sikhism then such questions will be obviously closed. @DarkKnight

Comment: I think we should allow it because it shares the same Gods, same Dharma and similar methods. This would open the scope to allow all Dharmic faiths though. The pathways to climb the hill are different but the summit is the same. The view from the top give rise to Vedas.